# When to add menu options to the fragment and when to add menu options to the main activity in android development?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have been following the Udacity's android app development course.
Sometimes they add the onOptionsItemSelected() method inside the fragment and sometimes they add it inside the parent activity.
I am a beginner to android development.
Can someone clarify that when are we supposed to add the onOptionsItemSelected() method inside the fragment and when inside the activity which contains the fragment ?
Also, it would be great if someone could give an intuitive explanation of a Fragment (how is it bound to the parent activity inside which it is present)

Answer (score 0):

In android option menus can be added to both `Activity` and `Fragment`. So that Activity and Fragments can have their own option menu's and their own callbacks..

Answer (score 0):

To your first question. A fragment represents a specific portion of your application, so if it's important to have a new menu item present while this portion is visible, you handle the item in the fragment. If a menu item should always be accessible you manage this item in the activity.

Not sure if I got your second question, but I try to answer anyway. First of all the developer side concerning fragments is pretty long but pretty good too. 
You can a reference of parent activity in a fragment by calling getActivity. That gives you the ability to make public calls like findViewById.